# IBM Bluemix : How the deploy an application on Bluemix?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am new to IBM Bluemix, till now the application (Spring-Hibernate-Rest App) was running on Tomcat Apache server of Oracle ecosystem but because of some requirement changes now it needs to be deployed on Bluemix (IBM), How can I migrate the Apache server to Bluemix ? Please let me know if there is any documentation/blog which I can refer to. Thanks

Edit:
I got this link which helped a lot [Liberty for java](https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/jazzeditorjava/), still searching for a decent source.

Comment: I really wonder when people who apparently hold jobs ask on SO if there *exists* documentation for something.

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone can help me out. I wonder when people who holds a huge rack of reputation on SO wastes time giving philosophy lectures to a naive.

Comment: Reputation is irrelevant here. I'm worried about the quality of the industry, when people are responsible for doing somewhat complicated things like migrating from one environment to another and they can't even use Google.

Comment: OK, then I would love to see a feature here (SO) when we type our question's Title it should also have option saying (First search on Google), anyways thanks for a bad experience with SO. Peace :)

Comment: I actually agree with you. Not necessarily messages saying "first search on Google", but tools that would allow people to fix certain types of problems by themselves. It's not useful for anyone that we tell people that "you have a typo in your code" or "you should use Google". As for your question, it doesn't fit the [QA format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of SO, so it will be closed (or forgotten) in any case. This is a lose-lose situation for all involved.

Answer (score 2):

IBM developerWorks hosts numerous tutorials for getting started on Bluemix, such as the following: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1306_king/1306_king.html and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-move-java-app-hybrid-cloud-bluemix-trs/index.html. You can also ask product-related questions at the IBM forum: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html. And as Kayaman points out, Google is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably figured out WebSphere Liberty is the Java app server in Bluemix.
There is a migration toolkit for migrating Tomcat to Liberty:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/index.html
More about Liberty can be found on http://wasdev.net

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this post about the migration from [LAMP to Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-migrate-lamp-app-to-bluemix-trs/index.html) to have a good starting point.

You should also note that moving from an on-premise solution to a Cloud Foundry-based one requires some considerations regarding the local file system:

- **Local file system storage is short-lived**. When an application instance crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will start with a new disk image. Although your application can write local files while it is running, the files will disappear after the application restarts.
- **Instances of the same application do not share a local file system**. Each application instance runs in its own isolated container. Thus if your application needs the data in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs to be shared across all running instances of the application, **the local file system should not be used**.
  For this reason local file system should not be used.

Moreover, I think you should take a look at [IBM Containers](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html): A container is basically an application with all its dependencies, that is stored in a portable, platform-independent module (the container).

Answer (score 0):

These should help. I know this is a couple of years late, but better late than never.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/tomcat/getting-started.html#getting_started
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/tomcat/index.html#tomcat_runtime
https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/get-started-tomcat